# Grails sometimes render wrong character encoding

Tags: tomcat, encoding, render, gsp, grails-3.3

I have a Grails application deployed in a tomcat. For some reason, sometimes render wrong characters, accented characters becomes a strange `?`.

Did someone face this problem and solved it?

I tried to find a solution but problems exposed there, are about a constant encoding problem, but in my case is random.

If I refresh the page, around 30% of times return wrong encoding, other 70% work correctly. What the ... it is going wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. Generate war with command `grails war`
2. Upload war to server (tomcat)
3. Open the app in the browser
4. Hit `F5` to refresh the page and the result is sometimes correct and sometimes wrong (random behaviour).

---

More info: I realized that this behaviour happens with gsp templates not gsp views

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. The Q  seems to be too broad as currently written.

Comment: I added the steps to reproduce the issue but I don’t think it’s a clue

Comment: I restarted tomcat and this seems to not be happening again. But I don’t know why! I will wait to see if happen again and provide por info.

Comment: We are experiencing what seems to be an exact replicate of your problem (war/happens sometimes/template). Only in Ajax-call to template though, and only message-labels are affected. Restart of Tomcat helps. Do you remember if you ever found out the cause of the problem?

Comment: I don’t remember now how that was solved but I think it was something with the server settings not a code issue.

Comment: I am no longer working on that project but I will try to find out if that problem was solved.